# Python UnicodeDecodeError on third-party python files after Linux system update

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-unicode

I started running into an issue after a recent system update on my Ubuntu machine. A lot of third-party python files suddenly are throwing UnicodeDecodeErrors like this:

```
ERROR : startup/gui/menus.py : Error loading Arnold module - "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte".
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/startup/gui/menus.py", line 123, in <module>
    import GafferArnoldUI
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/feature.py", line 139, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/arnold/7.2/python/GafferArnoldUI/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import ArnoldShaderUI
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/feature.py", line 139, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/arnold/7.2/python/GafferArnoldUI/ArnoldShaderUI.py", line 400, in <module>
    __translateNodeMetadata( arnold.AiNodeEntryIteratorGetNext( nodeIt ) )
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/arnold/7.2/python/GafferArnoldUI/ArnoldShaderUI.py", line 255, in __translateNodeMetadata
    presetValues = __enumPresetValues( param )
  File "/home/julius/bin/gaffer-1.3.2.0-linux/arnold/7.2/python/GafferArnoldUI/ArnoldShaderUI.py", line 132, in __enumPresetValues
    preset = arnold.AiEnumGetString( enum, len( presets ) )
  File "/opt/Autodesk/arnold/7.2.3.2/python/arnold/ai_enum.py", line 22, in AiEnumGetString
    return AtPythonStringToStr(_AiEnumGetString(enum_type, index))
  File "/opt/Autodesk/arnold/7.2.3.2/python/arnold/ai_types.py", line 36, in AtPythonStringToStr
    return str(astring)
  File "/opt/Autodesk/arnold/7.2.3.2/python/arnold/ai_types.py", line 28, in __str__
    return self.decode()
  File "/opt/Autodesk/arnold/7.2.3.2/python/arnold/ai_types.py", line 33, in decode
    return self.value.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here's an example of the third-party apps that stopped working:
https://github.com/gafferHQ/gaffer
https://arnoldrenderer.com/
These apps contain many python files and consequently editing the source files is not really an option for me, especially since they used to work just fine before the system update.

My initial feeling was that the locales on my system were messed up. I tried resetting them to factory defaults and rebooted to no avail:

```
> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My python version points to this:

```
> ll $(which python)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Sep  9 15:23 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

```
> ll /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Sep  9 15:23 /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/python3.10
```

I'm unfortunately a bit stuck here as I am not sure what to look out for. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand right that you upgraded Python? From which version? My guess is that Python started using UTF-8 by default (which is actually reasonable) and those files don't declare their encoding. An update to those libs so that they work with the newer Python should fix that.

Comment: Perhaps try to figure out which string is being decoded and where it comes from. 0xa0 is the non-breaking space in Latin-1 encoding. It is weird that a string begins with such character.

Comment: UTF8 doesn't allow bytes above 0x7F. That means the file isn't UTF8 to begin with. Changing the Python version or even OS version doesn't change the encoding of files. I suspect your locale settings before the update were *NOT* UTF8 and the code was reading using the default non-UTF8 encoding. When that changed, the code ended up using the wrong encoding.

Comment: If that's the case, you could modify the locale settings for a single terminal session and run your application. For a more permanent solution, you could convert those files to UTF8, assuming you know what the original encoding is. If not, you could use `chardet` to try and detect the encoding of the file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "UTF8 doesn't allow bytes above 0x7F" That's not *quite* true.

Comment: Yes, I should have worded this differently. A starting byte of ` 0xa0` is definitely invalid though

Comment: I double checked my apt history and indeed python was updated:
`python3.10:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.2, 3.10.12-1~22.04.3)`

I don't think it's anything specific with the files as they worked before. Also re-downloading and installing from github does not fix it either. 

I also tried changing the locale to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: What was the old version of Python you were using? Could it be Python 2.7?

Comment: The last trace I could find for a python update was in August. That was still python 3.10 however:
`python3.10:amd64 (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1.1, 3.10.12-1~22.04.2)`